# Why cannot I switch targeting between core and full framework from Visual Studio UI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

In a list I see either `Core 1|1.1|2.0` or full framework versions, but not all of them together. And this depends on what I write in `csproj` file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If I target some of `core` versions, then no full frameworks in a list and vice versa.

Here's a very nice [post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20) about multi-targeting.

[image]

Comment: "in a list" - in *what* list?

Comment: @MarcGravell Visual Studio UI, target framework, list... What might it be? =)  Dropdown list for selecting target framework. I added a screenshot

Comment: fyi there's an issue logged on the project system to allow choosing the target framework without restrictions: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/3024

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE has never really had good options for changing between entire platforms; the target framework has pretty much always been limited to versions within the same *family* - with the family determined by which template you chose when you created the project. Historically, changing between the framework *family* was a **much** bigger change than it is now - with foundational differences in the csproj making it a huge undertaking. Ultimately, this is simply an IDE limitation. As for why it hasn't been improved: presumably priorities by the teams involved vs perceived usage and the expected audience for the feature, and possibly deeper IDE technical reasons.

For now, changing the target framework *in a new-style csproj* is most easily done by hand - by editing the csproj. You can also multi-target in the new csproj format (using `<TargetFrameworks>`) in which case the drop-down you've shown in the screenshot becomes *completely* disabled - and you must change targets entirely by hand:

[image]

The good news is that it still has good options for *debugging* against multiple frameworks:

[image]

Comment: If I add multiple targets, it is then not clear how GAC references resolution behaves. VS UI allows me to reference assemblies from GAC when I target full framework. Must I additionally condition these references?

Comment: @PavelVoronin yeah, you're pretty much doing the references manually if you're multi-targeting; here's "Dapper"'s csproj, for example: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/Dapper.csproj - but you can also use variables rather than just the `$(TargetFramework)` - here's "protobuf-net"'s csproj: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.csproj - note the use of `<ImportLibs>` / `$(ImportLibs)`.

Comment: Sad. I like, when one CAN make everything manually editing configs. But I hate when it becomes the only option. =(

Comment: @PavelVoronin and that may improve - but tooling takes lots of work, and this is a niche requirement